# Use cell value as

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the value in cell F2 as the maximum value of a range selection within a larger range of numbers.

I've gotten as far as the below, but am getting a compile error: variable not defined.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectByValue(Rng1 As Range, MinimunValue As Double, MaximumValue As Double)

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Object

     'Check every cell in the range for matching criteria.
    For Each Cell In Rng1
        If Cell.Value >= MinimunValue And Cell.Value <= MaximumValue Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
            Else
                Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
            End If
        End If
    Next
     'Select the new range of only matching criteria
    MyRange.Select

End Sub


Sub CallSelectByValue()

     'Call the macro and pass all the required variables to it.
     'In the line below, change the Range, Minimum Value, and Maximum Value as needed
    Call SelectByValue(Range("A2:A41"), 1, Range(F2).Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
Call SelectByValue(Range("A2:A41"), 1, Range(F2).Value)
```

F2 needs to be quoted. It's not a variable that the code can see:

```
Call SelectByValue(Range("A2:A41"), 1, Range("F2").Value)
```

Comment: So the range I am selecting is actually full of empty cells. As a result I am getting error 91 object variable not set. How do i fix?

Comment: @MaxSather I think it fails at `MyRange.Select` which is still `Nothing` at the end, because ` If Cell.Value >= MinimunValue And Cell.Value <= MaximumValue Then` never happens. Possibly because minimum has a spelling error, but if not then without seeing your spreadsheet I can't guess. I suggest using the debugger by opening the VB editor, clicking inside `Sub CallSelectByValue()` and using Debug menu -> `Step Into (F8)` a lot to step through the code bit by bit. Hovering the mouse over the values will show you what they are as they run, or use Debug -> QuickWatch feature to track values.

Answer (score 1):

[TessellatingHeckler has the better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928154/4288101), but it's worth noting that you can get away with not using the quotes if you use brackets instead of `Range`.

```
Call SelectByValue( [A2:A41], 1, [F2].Value)
```

This syntax is generally discouraged because the brackets lead to ambiguous results which can make a mess at run time.